# Unity 3D not running on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, unity, wine, bug-reporting

[image]

When I try to open Unity the program always gives me this error.

I installed unity using wine and the original file from unity web site

I also tried to fix it from terminal with this command line than I found on internet, but nothing

**wine reg add 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' /v ProductId /t REG_SZ /d 12345-oem-0000001-54321**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity experimental is already released for ubuntu (x64) so why you are trying to install it through wine ? http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/